# How does nestjs get the cookie in the request?

Tags: nestjs

How does nestjs get the cookie in the request?

```
import { Get, Controller, Response, Request } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const l = console.log
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get('json')
  json(@Request() req){
    console.log(req.cookies) // undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to install `cookie-parser` middleware.

```
$ npm install --save cookie-parser
```

once the installation process is completed, simply bind middleware to your application:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
app.use(cookieParser());
```

read more here: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html

Comment: How to do so in e2e tests

Answer (score 17):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(5000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 6):

For everyone, who is looking at this question in 2022.
You can find it in the docs:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies

The other answers don't work, if you use Typescript.
You need to run (according to docs):

```
$ npm i cookie-parser
$ npm i -D @types/cookie-parser
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned by NKol and the docs still not worked for me.

I had to use

```
$ npm i cookie-parser
$ npm i -D @types/cookie-parser
```

and

```
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser'; 
...
app.use(cookieParser());
```

instead of  `import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';`as mentioned in the docs.