# How to refresh session cookie in nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, session-cookies, express-session

I have successfully implemented session authentication with NestJS. I have always used JWT and expire the access token very quickly. To get a new access token the frontend will need to refresh the access token.

I am trying to implement something similar to this with NestJS Session Authentication and I don't have a clue on how to go ahead with it as I couldn't find any resources talking about how to do this.

I wouldn't mind if you recommend a video or an article explaining this or just explaining how I should go ahead with this. Or do I even need to bother about refreshing?? What if someone had access to the session cookie?? I need clarification, please!!

Comment: Read express-session documents.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same challange on NestJS. So, according to my experience on this I recomend you to read the official NestJS - Cookies documentation just to ensure that you're using the best approach on this framework:

[NestJS - Cookies](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies)

For further learning and deep diving you should check on this answer hot to tackle this cookie implementation on this framework: [How does nestjs get the cookie in the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705859/how-does-nestjs-get-the-cookie-in-the-request)

And last but not least, this is a really useful post that uses both cookies and JWT components so I think you might want to read it and see if fits your needs:

[Nest.js cookie based JWT authentication](https://tigran.tech/nestjs-cookie-based-jwt-authentication/)

Regarding the "refreshing" process I asume you want to update/refresh the JWT token using the cookie so you will need to implement a middleware class that validates the "Expires" or "Max-age" attributes in order to check if the cookie has expired and then you'd be able to implement what you need.
Remember that cookies, have several attirbutes that you need to set in the cookie itself to make it secure against men-in-the-middle attacks or even get your cookie stolen.